# jQuery .click not firing up

Tags: jquery, click, attr

I have a link (imp), when I click on this link it shows a div.
On this div there is a minus sign to reduce this div.
When I reduce this div I'm adding a plus sign to bring up this div again.

the problem is just on the plus sign.

```
$('.plusStep1').click(function() {
  $('#plus').empty();
  $('#step1').css('display','block');
  $(".close-step1 img")
    .attr("src", "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_0AyNA9sRlIs/TAPH55KDj7I/AAAAAAAAIsU/_fjn6O2WguQ/s1600/424px-OCR-A_char_Hyphen-Minus.svg.png");
```

This code above seems to work only when I execute it in the console!

[Here is a test on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L95UP/).

Comment: It works here? Opera 12.01, what are you using? Are you getting any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: really? does the click on the plus sign works?
No errors, i tested it in FF and chrome.

Comment: Ah sorry, just used the imp link :-) Indeed the plus sign seems a little buggy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.click()` is not bound to a newly create element. You could create a seperate function which does what you want (on the plus click) and when you create the anchor call

```
bind('click', function() {
   seperateFunction();
})
```

update: Sorry, more easily `live` should do the trick (see [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/live/))

2nd update: see [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Answer (score 1):

`.click` doens't work on dynamically created elements, if you want to bind functions to elements you create after the DOM has loaded you're best to use `delegate`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

So to bind this function to all elements, whether created after the DOM or not, you could use something like;

```
$("#myContainer").on("click", ".PlusStep1", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("chosen");
});
```

Where all your `PlusStep1` class elements are children (or descendants) of the element with id `myContainer`., i.e. they're inside it, doesn't matter how deep.

Answer (score 0):

change your selector to `$('#plus').click(function() {` because the plus sign does not have th class `plusStep1` but has the id `plus`

[I saved the updated](http://jsfiddle.net/L95UP/3/) fiddle

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

        // Get a reference to the container.
        var containerStep1 = $( "#step1" );

        // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
        $( ".impaye" ).click(
        function( event ){
        // Prevent the default event.
        event.preventDefault();

        // Toggle the slide based on its current
        // visibility.
        if (containerStep1.is( ":visible" )){
        containerStep1.slideUp( 1000 );
        } else {
        containerStep1.slideDown( 1000 );
        }
        }
        );


        // CLOSE STEPS

        $(".close-step1 img").attr("src", "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_0AyNA9sRlIs/TAPH55KDj7I/AAAAAAAAIsU/_fjn6O2WguQ/s1600/424px-OCR-A_char_Hyphen-Minus.svg.png");
        // STEP 1
        $('.close-step1').click(function () {
            $('#plus').empty();
            $('.close-step1').clone().appendTo('#plus');
            $('#plus .close-step1').addClass('plusStep1');

            containerStep1.slideToggle("slow", function () {
                if ($("#step1").is(':visible')) {
                    $(".close-step1 img").attr("src", "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_0AyNA9sRlIs/TAPH55KDj7I/AAAAAAAAIsU/_fjn6O2WguQ/s1600/424px-OCR-A_char_Hyphen-Minus.svg.png");
                }
                else {
                    $(".close-step1 img").attr("src", "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/OCR-A_char_Plus_Sign.svg");
                    $('.plusStep1').bind('click',plustep1);
                }

            });
        });
        function plustep1() {
            $('#plus').empty();
            $('#step1').css('display','block');
            $(".close-step1 img").attr("src", "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_0AyNA9sRlIs/TAPH55KDj7I/AAAAAAAAIsU/_fjn6O2WguQ/s1600/424px-OCR-A_char_Hyphen-Minus.svg.png");

        }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the follwing

```
 $('.plusStep1').live('click',function() {

//---------Your Code----------
})

or 
 $('.plusStep1').bind('click',function() {
//---------Your Code----------
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making this harder than it needs to be. Maybe in trying it this way it will work out for you.

html

```
<a href="#" class="trigger">img</a>

<div id="togglable" style="display:none;">
  <a href="#" class="trigger">Hide me</a>
  content content content
</div>
```

js

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
  $("#togglable").toggle();
});
```

And then you can add a bit of logic to change the src properties of your trigger elements to incorporate your + and - images.

Benefit being there is no need for live bindings.